# path parameter is being ignored when storing cookie

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, cookies

Using JavaScript I'm setting a session cookie on the page [www.mydomain.com/home/data](http://www.mydomain.com/home/data) with path='/' so I can access it from any page:

`document.cookie="mydata=test;domain=.mydomain.com;path=/"`

but when I look at the cookie that was stored, it's path is '/home/data' and is only accessible on that page. My browser is Chrome on Windows 10. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your example is not a valid string. The double quote after **test** ends your string too early. Get used to check your console for errors.

Comment: This is why you wear glasses. Completely missed that when answering.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped when I constructed the example. The actual code does not have the extra quote

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to specify domain when creating a session cookie. Just specify `path`.

```
document.cookie="mydata=test; path=/"
```

Also, if you'd like it to truly be a session-only cookie, add the `expires` value to make sure it is set to zero.

```
document.cookie="mydata=test; expires=0; path=/"
```

Edit: as pointed out above by Lain, you ended your string with a double quote after `test;`, invalidating the string. Updating my own answer for brevity.

Comment: Yep, I admit I missed that. Lain's comment above pointed that out.

Comment: Thanks Autumn, but the behaviour is the same if I remove the domain and set expiry to 0. As I replied to Lain, I mistyped the example. The actual code does not have the extra quote